# Compute the pmf $p_k$ of a random variable K := Y + X

Tags: probability

Having a table of data for pmf $p(y,x)$.

How is the computation done for pmf $p_k$ where $K := Y + X$

Table with table could look like this:

```
------------------------------
| p(x,y) |  1   |  2  |  3   | 
------------------------------
|   1    | 0.05 | 0.1 | 0.3  |
------------------------------
|   2    | 0.2  | 0.3 | 0.05 |
------------------------------
```

How is it done? I'm a little confused at this subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$
p_k = \sum_{x+y=k} p(y,x)
$$